# wordpress add field to post_class

Tags: posts, post-class

I need to add a custom field to my article post but not sure how to add an additional class to it.

Currently the classes get pulled through like this `<?php post_class($classes); ?>`.

However I need to add a custom field to this as well. To demonstrate ive added a class= but this doesnt work as class= is being added twice.

```
<?php post_class($classes); ?> class="<?php the_field( "size" ); ?>
```

So i need post_class and the_field to work together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first store your field value in a variable after your loop just before the posts HTML tags start:

```
<?php
$size = the_field( "size" );
?>
```

And then add this variable to the post class function:

```
<?php post_class($size); ?>
```